# Bootstrap3 positioning 3 elements with equal spacing in a div with icons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building a bootstrap 3 site and everything is basically done except for the `footer`.
I divided the `footer` into 3 parts, while everything is located inside a `div` with a class of `container`. The large `container` consists of 3 smaller `div`s:

`<div class="col-sm-2">` with some text in it.
`<div class="col-sm-4">` with some more text in it.
`<div class="col-sm-6">` which should hold 3 horizontal links (with equal spacing between them) + icon (64x64) of social network.

I want to equally space the elements in the third `div` and place an icon next to the next (now the icon is trimmed for some reason).

Any help is appreciated, Here's a fiddle with the current build:
http://jsfiddle.net/uv99wj6q/

Just to be clear, im adding a screen shot of the current state vs wanted state:
The red circle are the icons (64x64) I need to add. As you can see, in the upper screen shot, the `linkedin` text kind of overlaps \ trims the icon.
[image]

Comment: Don't really understand your problem, but maybe something like http://jsfiddle.net/uv99wj6q/1/ would sort you out?

Comment: Morpheus please see my updated post with the added screenshot to make things clearer.

Comment: Made another example http://jsfiddle.net/uv99wj6q/2/. Look at g+

Answer (score 1):

As Bootstrap allows you to nest its grid, I think a solution might be to split the third column, `.col-sm-6`, into three equally sized columns. You do this by adding a `.row` that consists of three `.col-sm-4` columns. You could also add the class `.text-center` to center the text.

You might think that three `.col-sm-2` columns would be needed as you want it to be nested into a `col-sm-6` column, but each nested grid consists of 12 columns.

```css
.footer {
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container">
  <div class="row footer">
    <div class="col-xs-2"><h6>Copyright</h6></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><h6>About</h6></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h6>Follow Me</h6>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">LinkedIn</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">Facebook</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">Google</div>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```